# MongoDB Compass loading forever on start page

Tags: mongodb

When I start MongoDB Compass 1.18, it loads forever and never starts. 
It displays the word "LOADING..."
under a logo consisting of two blue squares:
                    [image: "LOADING..." page]

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use the community beta version and use the latest version of mongodb server whic is 4.0.

It works for me.

-ced